# putting code declaration into words (reference operator and dereference operator confusion)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, dereference

hi i'm a beginner in c and c++ and is completely confused by these lines of codes,i don't need to know the result, just wanna understand the 2nd line properly, the following is the code

```
float f = 7.0;
short s = * (short * )&f;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you reinterpret the first 16 bits of the float as a short.

What happens: you first obtain the address of the float, next you convert that pointer to a `short*` pointer, this is done so you take `16` bits at a time instead of `32`. Finally you query the pointer for the value.

Since `7.0` is represented as (http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html):

```
00000000 00000000 01110000 01000000
```

The result is `0` in case you took the second short, it would be `16 496`

For instance if you would use:

```
float f = 7.0068;
```

then the result would be: `14 261`